# How can the margins around a table set to 0pt?

Tags: tables, spacing, nesting

I need to put a table inside another table, and would like to set the outside margins of the inner table to 0pt. How can I do this (in particular for tabularx, but hopefully this would be the same for any table environment)?

Comment: `\begin{tabularx}{1in}{@{}ll@{}}...\end{tabularx}`. Why do you need a table inside a table?

Comment: @TH.: Why not? I do this also from time to time to align a normal `tabular` with other things.

Comment: @Martin: It seems like the 1990's HTML version of page layout.

Comment: @TH.: I know, but for simply things it is straight forward. I use the Web 2.0/CSS version of page layout as well (i.e. positioning using TikZ).

Comment: @TH.: I am using it for creating a particular form which basically needs a long table over multiple pages with a header and footer which are also in table form. if there is a better way to create such a layout, I am open to it

Comment: @txwikinger: As you described it, it "needs ... a header and footer ... in table form." I'm not sure how anyone could give advice without actually knowing what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 84):

If you are talking about the left and right margins of a `tabular` (be careful with the term 'table'), they can be removed using `@{}` as the first and last element in the column definition:

```
\begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}}
```

This replace the normal skip with the content inside the `{}`, which is empty in this case. This also works for `tabularx`, `array` etc.

Comment: This worked somewhat with the cells of the tabular, but not with the hlines

Comment: @txwikinger: Works fine for me. Is your inner table a `tabularx` or `tabular`? The `\hline`s will be as long as the official `tabularx` width, but should be shorten for an `tabular`.

Comment: @Martin Scharrer: The inner table is tabularx the outer table is longtable.

Comment: @txwikinger: You might need to reduce the width then. Without seeing your code it's hard to tell.

Comment: @Martin Scharrer: I use \textwidth as the parameter for tabularx at the moment. Can I use something else to just let it fill all the space available? The cell (I use a background color for the cell) does go to the border of the outer table. The hline is still where the cell stopped before putting @{} into the format.

Comment: @txwikinger: I assume you use `tabularx` then to have two or more columns with the same width? Otherwise "just let it fill all the space available" could be done with a normal `tabular`. AFAIK you can't tell `tabularx` to be as small as possible. You would need to reduce the width manually. Using the full `\textwidth` sounds wrong when used inside another table.

Comment: @Martin Scharrer: I use tabularx to allow two columns to fill any space not used (like {X|X|c|c|c} as format). I tried the same with tabular ( and {l|l|c|c|c}) and get the same with the hlines

Comment: @txwikinger: It works fine with `tabular` for me. Maybe post a complete example.

Comment: This solution is fine for the left-right margins, but what about top and bottom?

Comment: Is it possible to set this as a default so that you don't have to put those `@{}` into dozens of tabulars?

Comment: @KonradHöffner: I'm sure that is possible someone. Feel free to ask this as a new, follow-up question. Please add a link to this answer or the question in your new question.

Answer (score 11):

If you also want to get rid of the margin outside the `tabular`, use the `flushleft`:

```
\begin{flushleft}
\begin{tabular}{@{}l l}
Content & Content
\end{tabular}
\end{flushleft}
```