# Remove vertical padding of a table inside a longtable

Tags: tables

I want to have two row heading for my longtable and I am using this:

```
\documentclass[12pt,landscape,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,czech]{babel}
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{cp{1.7cm}p{1.7cm}p{1.7cm}c}
\parbox{1.4cm}{blable\-bloblu} &
\multicolumn{3}{l}{
\begin{tabular}{@{}p{1.7cm}p{1.7cm}p{1.7cm}@{}}
\multicolumn{3}{c}{onetwothreefour}\\
one &   two  & three
\end{tabular}
}
& \parbox{0.7cm}{bla\-ble} \\
\hline
one & two & three & four & five
\endhead
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

It looks almost great, only the "one two three" row is vertically a bit too height and not alligned with "bloblu" and "ble" (see screenshot):[image]Any idea how to put it lower? (Simpler solutions to make a two row aligned heading are welcome too.) (The solution to remove horizontal padding goes comes from here: [How can the margins around a table set to 0pt?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16258/how-can-the-margins-around-a-table-set-to-0pt)

**Update:** With @Heiko Oberdiek suggestions, I produced this document:

```
\documentclass[12pt,landscape,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,czech]{babel}
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{p{1.4cm} p{0.7cm} p{0.7cm} p{0.7cm} p{0.7cm}c}
\strut Název \strut & 
\multicolumn{3}{l}{\begin{tabular}{@{}p{0.7cm}p{0.7cm}p{0.7cm}@{}}\multicolumn{3}{c}{Distribuce} \\ Svět &   ČR  & DVD \end{tabular}} &
\parbox{0.7cm}{\strut Pů\-vod \strut}   
\\
\end{longtable}
\normalsize
\end{document}
```

It looks like this ("Původ" is way to high):[image]
This is my actual document produced by stripping down almost everything.

**Result:** without `[-0.3pt]` applied:[image]

With `[-0.3pt]` applied: [image]
(I guess one needs to download the pictures and then look at them in succession to see the difference, but there is a difference. The last look is fully satisfactory, thanks!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution using `multirow`, and `booktabs`, whose rule commands have some vertical padding (this padding can be changed with the `\aboverulesep` and `belowrulesep` lengths):

```
\documentclass[12pt,landscape,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{longtable, multirow}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,czech]{babel}
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{p{1.4cm} p{0.7cm} p{0.7cm} p{0.7cm} p{0.7cm}}
  \toprule
  \multirow{2}{*}{ Název} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Distribuce} &
  \multirow{2}{*}[1.25pt]{\parbox{0.7cm}{ Pů\-vod}} \\
    & Svět & ČR & DVD & \\
  \bottomrule
\end{longtable}
\vskip1cm

\begin{longtable}{cp{1.7cm}p{1.7cm}p{1.7cm}c}
  \multirow{2}{*}[1.2pt]{\parbox{1.4cm}{blable\-bloblu}} &
  \multicolumn{3}{c}{onetwothreefour}& \multirow{2}{*}[1.2pt]{\parbox{0.7cm}{bla\-ble}} \\
      & one & two & three & \\
  \midrule
  one & two & three & four & five
  \endhead
\end{longtable}

\normalsize
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The multirow and multicolumn approach works the best (but there is still one pixel different visible even in your image - I will just have to live by it, not that bug of a deal actually). Thanks!

Comment: ??? In  my pdfviewer, there's no difference (or if there is, it's less than 0.1pt, measured with the tool provided by SumatraPDF): I adjusted the vertical placement with the optional argument of `\multirow`. Anyway, it's easy to change the value

Comment: Well, there is a small difference, using `[-0.3pt]` fixes it. Thanks for the option!I added screenshots to the answer. It is true it was only clearly visible when I magnified it to 400 %, but that is the point of Tex, that even such small differences affect the overall appearance of the document, no?

Answer (score 1):

Table rows automatically add struts, which is not done in `\parbox`. Thus adding `\strut`s help here to get better alignments (with `\arraystretch` defined with its default `1`):

```
\documentclass[12pt,landscape,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,czech]{babel}
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{cp{1.7cm}p{1.7cm}p{1.7cm}c}
\parbox{1.4cm}{\strut blable\-bloblu\strut} &
\multicolumn{3}{l}{
\begin{tabular}{@{}p{1.7cm}p{1.7cm}p{1.7cm}@{}}
\multicolumn{3}{c}{onetwothreefour}\\
one &   two  & three
\end{tabular}
}
& \parbox{0.7cm}{\strut bla\-ble\strut} \\
\hline
one & two & three & four & five
\endhead
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Alternative version with inner `tabular`s instead of `\parbox`:

```
\begin{longtable}{cp{1.7cm}p{1.7cm}p{1.7cm}c}
  \begin{tabular}{@{}p{1.4cm}@{}}blable\-bloblu\end{tabular} &
\multicolumn{3}{l}{
\begin{tabular}{@{}p{1.7cm}p{1.7cm}p{1.7cm}@{}}
\multicolumn{3}{c}{onetwothreefour}\\
one &   two  & three
\end{tabular}
}
& \begin{tabular}{@{}p{.7cm}@{}}bla\-ble\end{tabular} \\
\hline
one & two & three & four & five
\endhead
\end{longtable}
```

Second MWE with inner `tabular`s:

```
\documentclass[12pt,landscape,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,czech]{babel}
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{p{1.4cm} p{0.7cm} p{0.7cm} p{0.7cm} p{0.7cm}c}
Název &
\multicolumn{3}{l}{\begin{tabular}{@{}p{0.7cm}p{0.7cm}p{0.7cm}@{}}\multicolumn{
\\ Svět &   ČR  & DVD \end{tabular}} &
\begin{tabular}{@{}p{0.7cm}@{}}Pů\-vod\end{tabular}
\\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result 2nd MWE with tabular]

Comment: Thanks. This is weird. `\strut` fixes my MWE, but when I try to apply it to my actual document, it does not work. I stripped it down and came up with another MWE (please see the original question at the bottom) that misbehabes even with `\strut` - using tabular seems to have the same effect. Any idea why it does not work on the second MWE?