# No margins around tabular by default?

Tags: tables, margins

How can I set the margins around all tabulars to zero by default?

The margins around a single tabular can be removed using `@{}`, see below, but I have dozens of tables and would like to have a single switch for all of them.

```
\begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}}
```

Source: [How can the margins around a table set to 0pt?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16258/how-can-the-margins-around-a-table-set-to-0pt/16261)

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik unfortunately not, that removes the space between columns in the table.

Comment: One way would be to define your own environment which adds the `@{}`. `\newenvironment{mytabular}[1]{\tabular{@{}#1@{}}}{\endtabular}`. By renaming `tabular` to e.g. `origtabular` first (`\let\origtabular\tabular \let\endorigtabular\endtabular`) you can even patch the environment and keeping the orginal name.

Answer (score 3):

Just for fun.  This trims off the edge using a `\makebox`.  The `\fbox` is just to show the actual dimensions.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\let\oldtabular=\tabular
\let\oldendtabular=\endtabular
\def\tabular{\bgroup\sbox0\bgroup\oldtabular}
\def\endtabular{\oldendtabular\egroup
  \makebox[\dimexpr\wd0-2\tabcolsep][c]{\usebox0}%
\egroup}

\begin{document}
\fboxsep=0pt
\fbox{\begin{tabular}{lr}
  this&is\\
  why&I\\
  hate&making\\
  My&own MWE
\end{tabular}}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]