# Remove horizontal padding from nested tabular tables

Tags: tables, colortbl

#### Update

Both [David Carlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/579359/223558)'s and [Skillmon](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/579360/223558)'s answers were great (and posted within 10 seconds of each other), but SO would only let me mark one as correct, so I encourage anyone encountering this question to do as I did and try both (as both were solutions to different missteps by me with the same result).

#### Original Post:

How would one modify the horizontal spacing/padding from the following nested `tabulars`, so that the highlighting in the two relevant cells would touch the left and right cell borders?

I looked through [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6987737/removing-white-space-in-a-table), [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2756236/how-to-remove-extra-space-between-two-tables-in-latex) [answers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16258/how-can-the-margins-around-a-table-set-to-0pt) but was unable to find a solution that worked.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Table is as follows:

```
\begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \caption{Caption above table.}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|l|p{5cm}|}
        \hline
        
        % column headers
        Record & Prepend & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Name} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Value} \\ \hline
        
        % A (ipv4 records)
        \texttt{A} & www & 
        \begin{tabular}{@{\hskip3pt}l}
            \colorbox{white}{%
                \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l}
                    \texttt{mydomain.tld}
                \end{tabular}
            } \\
            \colorbox{yellow}{%
                \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l}
                    \texttt{autoconfig.mydomain.tld}\\
                    \texttt{imap.mydomain.tld}\\
                    \texttt{mail.mydomain.tld}\\
                    \texttt{pop.mydomain.tld}\\ 
                    \texttt{smtp.mydomain.tld}
                \end{tabular}
            }
        \end{tabular} & \texttt{111.222.111.222} \\ \hline
        
        % AAAA (ipv6) records
        \texttt{AAAA} & www & 
        \begin{tabular}{@{}l}
            \colorbox{white}{%
                \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l}
                    \texttt{mydomain.tld}
                \end{tabular}
            } \\
            \colorbox{yellow}{%
                \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l}
                \texttt{autoconfig.mydomain.tld}\\
                \texttt{imap.mydomain.tld}\\
                \texttt{mail.mydomain.tld}\\
                \texttt{pop.mydomain.tld}\\ 
                \texttt{smtp.mydomain.tld}
            \end{tabular}
            }
        \end{tabular} & \texttt{aaaa:bbbb:cccc:dddd::1234} \\ \hline
    
        % MX records
        \texttt{MX} & www & \texttt{mydomain.tld} & \texttt{1 mail.mydomain.tld} \\ \hline
        
        % NS records
        \texttt{NS} & & \texttt{@} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}\texttt{ns1.nameserver.tld}\\ \texttt{ns2.nameserver.tld}\end{tabular} \\ \hline
        \texttt{PTR} & & \texttt{@} & \texttt{mydomain.tld} \\ \hline
        
        % TXT for DMARC
        
        \rowcolor{yellow} \texttt{TXT} & & \texttt{\_dmarc} & \texttt{"v=DMARC1; p=quarantine; pct=100; rua=mailto: postmaster@domain.tld"} \\ \hline
        
        % TXT for DKIM
        \rowcolor{yellow} \texttt{TXT} & & \texttt{default.\_domainkey} &  \texttt{"v=DKIM1; k=rsa; s=email; p=<DKIM key>"} \\ \hline
        
        % TXT for SPF
        \texttt{TXT} & & \texttt{@} & \texttt{"v=spf1 a mx ~all"} \\ \hline
        
        % TXT for Site description
        \texttt{TXT} & www & \texttt{@} & \texttt{"<description of site>"} \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

**PS** sorry about the indentation, I'm not sure what I was thinking.  All I can say is that it seemed like a good idea at the time.

[image: My table]

Comment: Don't use `\colorbox` but `\cellcolor` before the nested `tabular`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `\cellcolor` instead of `\colorbox` and consequently removing the outer paddings from the nested `tabular`s:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[]{colortbl}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \caption{Caption above table.}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|l|p{5cm}|}
        \hline
        
        % column headers
        Record & Prepend & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Name} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Value} \\ \hline
        
        % A (ipv4 records)
        \texttt{A} & www & 
        \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
            \cellcolor{white}%
            \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}
              \texttt{mydomain.tld}
            \end{tabular} \\
            \cellcolor{yellow}%
              \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}
                    \texttt{autoconfig.mydomain.tld}\\
                    \texttt{imap.mydomain.tld}\\
                    \texttt{mail.mydomain.tld}\\
                    \texttt{pop.mydomain.tld}\\ 
                    \texttt{smtp.mydomain.tld}
                \end{tabular}
        \end{tabular} & \texttt{111.222.111.222} \\ \hline
        
        % AAAA (ipv6) records
        \texttt{AAAA} & www & 
        \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
            \cellcolor{white}%
              \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}
                    \texttt{mydomain.tld}
                \end{tabular}
            \\
            \cellcolor{yellow}%
              \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}
                \texttt{autoconfig.mydomain.tld}\\
                \texttt{imap.mydomain.tld}\\
                \texttt{mail.mydomain.tld}\\
                \texttt{pop.mydomain.tld}\\ 
                \texttt{smtp.mydomain.tld}
            \end{tabular}
        \end{tabular} & \texttt{aaaa:bbbb:cccc:dddd::1234} \\ \hline
    
        % MX records
        \texttt{MX} & www & \texttt{mydomain.tld} & \texttt{1 mail.mydomain.tld} \\ \hline
        
        % NS records
        \texttt{NS} & & \texttt{@} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}\texttt{ns1.nameserver.tld}\\ \texttt{ns2.nameserver.tld}\end{tabular} \\ \hline
        \texttt{PTR} & & \texttt{@} & \texttt{mydomain.tld} \\ \hline
        
        % TXT for DMARC
        
        \rowcolor{yellow} \texttt{TXT} & & \texttt{\_dmarc} & \texttt{"v=DMARC1; p=quarantine; pct=100; rua=mailto: postmaster@domain.tld"} \\ \hline
        
        % TXT for DKIM
        \rowcolor{yellow} \texttt{TXT} & & \texttt{default.\_domainkey} &  \texttt{"v=DKIM1; k=rsa; s=email; p=<DKIM key>"} \\ \hline
        
        % TXT for SPF
        \texttt{TXT} & & \texttt{@} & \texttt{"v=spf1 a mx ~all"} \\ \hline
        
        % TXT for Site description
        \texttt{TXT} & www & \texttt{@} & \texttt{"<description of site>"} \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

as commented you could use `\cellcolor` but you are adding white space to the right but not the left of all tables

```
colorbox{yellow}{%
                \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l}
                    \texttt{autoconfig.mydomain.tld}\\
                    \texttt{imap.mydomain.tld}\\
                    \texttt{mail.mydomain.tld}\\
                    \texttt{pop.mydomain.tld}\\ 
                    \texttt{smtp.mydomain.tld}
                \end{tabular}
            }
```

You are avoiding adding a space token to the left of the tabular with `{%` but you are adding a space after the tabular (but inside the `\colorbox`) which you could avoid with `\end{tabular}%` or by putting the closing `}` from `\colorbox` immediately after `\end{tabular}`

Similarly you are removing the tabcolsep padding on the left but not on the right as you have `@{}l`  rather than `@{}l@{}` as the preamble of the nested tables.

Comment: Come on, 10 seconds?

Comment: @Skillmon not my fault if you are so slow, but there is almost no overlap in the answers actually, mine shows what's wrong and your says what the OP should do instead so I guess you'll get the tick:-)

Comment: But I corrected your answer. Now irregardless of who gets the tick, it is mine!

Comment: @Skillmon concentrating so hard to omit the `u` from `colour`

Comment: I know exactly how you feel, same for me, and I'm not even British (but prefer the British spelling generally).

Comment: Hahaha I've never seen something like this before.  I picked @Skillmon's because it was closest to the top, I tried it first, and it worked first.  But both are excellent solutions.